# I need to get the user details or ip address of the users who are all downloading the my pip package

Tags: azure-artifacts

I have created Azure artifact feed internally to the organization and I want to get the user details like IP address who are all downloading the package? how to get it ?

I am publishing the artifact feed and tried azure end points nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

Azure Artifacts does not provide that information through any mechanism, sorry.